# When updating a row, how do I validate that the existing row contains a value with Laravel form requests?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

In Laravel 5, using a form request to act as a validation gate, and given the code below:

**Controller**

```
public function decline(Request $request, InviteDeclineRequest $validation, $id)
{
    $invite = Invite::find($id);
    $invite->status = 'declined';
    $invite->save();   
}
```

**FormRequest**

```
class InviteDeclineRequest extends Request {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            # this is referring to the incoming data, 
            # not the existing data 
            'status': 'pending', 
        ];
    }

}
```

How can I change the above validation ruleset to say, the incoming input is only valid if the existing record's status is set to 'pending'. I.e don't allow a declined invite unless the existing is pending.

**Option 1:**
Put this logic in the controller. Maybe the above isn't considered a part of validation, (although I would argue that it is), and so doesn't belong in the FormRequest.

**Option 2:** 
Put the logic in the Authorise method of method of the FormRequest. The only downside to this is that the authorise should be for access control, not data validation.

**Option 3:**
Extend form request to include a third method that validates existing data as well as incoming data. Slightly painful as I need to make sure it gets called as part of the request cycle.

**Option 4:**
Add a custom validation rule:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your custom `InviteDeclineRequest` class method `all` to add `id` to data that will be validated:

```
public function all()
{
        $data = parent::all();
        $segments = $this->segments();
        $id = intval(end($segments));
        if ($id != 0) {
           $data['id'] = $id;
        } 
        return $data;
}
```

and now in `rules` you can use it:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id' => ['required', 'exists:invites,id,status,pending']
    ];
}
```

to make sure record you edit has status `pending`.

Comment: You can access the route parameter like `$this->id` and validate them with `'id' => 'required|exists:invites,id,status,pending' . $this->id`. [More about this here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update).